# Setting/Configuration for external nuget services on AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

Is it possible to configure nuget endpoints for other nuget services other than the default location on AppHarbor?  My current build fails because AppHarhor cannot find the nuget references as they don't exist on the default nuget server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your custom package feed in the `NuGet.targets` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' ">
                <PackageSource Include="myurl" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

... you should be fine.